# using keyboard shortcuts with non-US keyboard

Tags: front-end, keyboard

There are several keyboard shortcuts that do not seem to work for me. I am using a German keyboard. I think this only happens when I have to use a modifier key that does not have to be used in case of a US keyboard.

Example: One can comment/uncomment code by pressing the shortcut "Alt+/". However, on the German keyboard, the "/" sign is on the 7-key and reached by pressing "shift-7". So, I will have to press "Alt-Shift-7", which Mathematica does not recognize as Alt-/.

There are other examples where a certain symbol needs Shift or Alt-Gr to be reached; in each case the shortcut does not work.

Any ideas to make all this work also for the German keyboard layout, short of changing the actual shortcuts?

Comment: Any particular reason you eliminate *changing the actual shortcuts* as a solution?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess it would require changing the KeyTranslations File, and I would actually have to think about which shortcut I want to choose... However, there might be a ready-to-use version? Then it would be fine.

Comment: The same happens with Brazilian Keyboard. I haven't problem because I use Mac. But my team has problem to comment code. They created some strange windows macros  to make it works. It would be nice to have a more standard solution.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows one solution is to use the key combo

Alt + E + O

This effectively accesses the **E**dit menu and the Un/Comment command. However, this does not work in full screen mode.

If this bothers you, then the best option is probably to write an  [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script.

Here is the script that I have been using

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class NotebookFrame 

!c::
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard = 
    Send ^c
    Clipwait, 1
    StringLeft, OutputVar, Clipboard, 2 

    if(OutputVar = "(*") ; If commented we uncomment
    {
        StringTrimLeft, OutputVar, Clipboard, 2  
        StringTrimRight, OutputVar, OutputVar, 2
        Clipboard := OutputVar
    }
    else ; Else we comment it
    {
        Clipboard := "(*" . Clipboard . "*)"
    }

    Send ^v
    Clipboard := ClipSaved
return
```